# Cannot run the script when creating a docker container

Tags: docker

I am using docker-compose to build an Image and run a container. In my Dockferfile, I have included this line:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
CMD /bin/bash
```

This entrypoint script does exist (I did try getting into a container and it exists) and the working directory of the scrip also correct. The script itself is:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -u

echo "==> Executing master image entrypoint ..."

echo "-> Setting up ROS"
source "./devel/setup.bash"
#chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSBO
echo "==> Container ready"
exec "$@"
```

When I run:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: for 45f1dcaf575e_rosdocker_master_1  Cannot start service master: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"entrypoint.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

ERROR: for master  Cannot start service master: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"entrypoint.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the script is in the working directory access it with `./`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the script has the right permissions, which you can set by calling `chmod +x entrypoint.sh`, you can use a `RUN` instruction in the Dockerfile:

```
...
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
...
```

Also, set the full path on the `ENTRYPOINT` setting, e.g., `/entrypoint.sh`, if it is in the root:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```